# Exported Tensorflow Model not Preserving Placeholder Shape

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am using `exporter` from `tensorflow.contrib.session_bundle` to save out my model:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None,) + (100, 200) + (1,))
....
saver = tf_saver.Saver(sharded=True)
model_exporter = exporter.Exporter(saver)
model_exporter.init(
    sess.graph.as_graph_def(),
    named_graph_signatures={
        'inputs': exporter.generic_signature({'images': x}),
        'outputs': exporter.generic_signature({'classes': y})})
```

and then I load the model back in (`session_bundle` from `tensorflow.contrib.session_bundle`):

```
sess, meta_graph_def = session_bundle.load_session_bundle_from_path(input)
```

However when I inspect the Placeholder tensor corresponding to the input x, I see no shape information:

```
> sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name(input_name)
<tf.Tensor 'Placeholder:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=float32>
```

Is this by design or is there some bug causing the shape to be lost?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer from a colleague:

"The `exporter.generic_signature` call (when building the `named_graph_signatures`) populates the map of the `generic_signature` as defined here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle/manifest.proto#L69

The value in the map is a `TensorBinding`, which by itself is simply the tensor-name. See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle/manifest.proto#L20

So it is expected that the shape will not be retained and the name should sufficiently identify the tensor."

Comment: Right but I am taking the tensor name which I am [reading out of the protobuf](https://gist.github.com/cancan101/31df34ca5dd971338cad8ca85bc1d8e2) and then calling `get_tensor_by_name` which does resolve the name to the actual tensor object.

Comment: Hi Alex, it seems like as long as the tensor info can be retrieved using the name, this should work. Can you elaborate on what the specific issue might be?

Comment: I still don't follow why the shape of the output Tensor is retained by the shape of the input tensors are not.